# How can I distinguish same variable with different order? (drug prescription data)

Tags: r, date, time

I'm trying to analyse drug prescription data with dates.

Here is the code for my data:

```
structure(list(id = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L), claim = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), start_date = structure(c(12267, 
12298, 12626, 12818, 12846, 12877, 12907, 12938, 13091, 13121, 
13152), class = "Date"), drug = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "b"), total.price = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), dose = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), IBD = c("CD", "CD", "CD", "CD", 
"CD", "CD", "CD", "CD", "CD", "CD", "CD"), naivety = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), diff_drug = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -11L), groups = structure(list(id = 4:6, 
    .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3L, 4:11), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

What I'm trying to calculate is the start date and end date of the drug prescriptions for each id.
First, I grouped data by "id" and "drug" variables.

If the variable 'discontinuation' ==1, the person's end date will be the discontinuation date.
If the variable 'discontinuation' == 0, the person's end date will be the last date of the prescriptions(max(start_date)).

I tried to calculate this by the code below.

```
bio_naive <- bio_naive %>% arrange(id,start_date) %>%  mutate(Diff = lead(start_date) - (start_date))

bio_naive <- bio_naive %>% group_by(id, drug) %>% mutate(discontinuation = ifelse(Diff > 90, '1', '0')) 

bio_naive$discontinuation[is.na(bio_naive $discontinuation)] <- 0

bio_naive %>%
  group_by(id,drug) %>% 
  summarise(discont=max(discontinuation), start = min(start_date, na.rm = TRUE), dc_final_date = if_else(any(discontinuation == 1), start_date[match(1, discontinuation)], max(start_date)))
```

However, the problem arose with 'id6, drug b'
I want to seperate the date of '**two drug b prescriptions**' like the results in the picture below,
but somehow it is combined in my code earlier.

Therefore, I want to ask two questions regard this data.

1. Is there any solutions to distinguish '**two drug b prescriptions**' 'id6'?
2. Is there a code to calculate total price between id and drug groups during follow-up period (from start to until the dc_final_date)?

Desired Results
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I solved first Q by this code.  `bio_naive <- bio_naive %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(ep = cumsum(diff_drug != 0 ) + 1) 
bio_naive1_dc <- bio_naive1_dc %>% group_by(id,drug) %>% mutate(discontinuation = ifelse(Diff > 90, '1', '0')) 
bio_naive1_dc $discontinuation[is.na(bio_naive1_dc $discontinuation)] <- 0
bio_naive1_dc  %>%  group_by(id,drug,ep) %>% summarise(discon=max(discontinuation), start = min(start_date, na.rm = TRUE), end = if_else(any(discontinuation == 1), start_date[match(1, discontinuation)], max(start_date))) %>% arrange(id, ep, drug)
` any ideas for the 2nd Q?

Comment: hi the "discontinuation" variable you describe is not in the dummy data

Comment: @DPH, It can be caluated by my code above, which is, `bio_naive <- bio_naive %>% group_by(id, drug) %>% mutate(discontinuation = ifelse(Diff > 90, '1', '0')) 
bio_naive$discontinuation[is.na(bio_naive $discontinuation)] <- 0`

Comment: Is there as solution to distinguish the two instances of `drug==b` in `id==6`. No... we cannot know what is in your mind that makes these different. You need to formulate a rule and then express it in natural language.

Comment: @IRTFM, As I did in my first comment, I want to make it with ep(episode). So I solved it by making (id==6)'s 3 prescription data (b--> a --> b) as episode 1,2,3 by this code `bio_naive <- bio_naive %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(ep = cumsum(diff_drug != 0 ) + 1)`